# Help with the Laplacian Formula

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone please give me the formula of the Laplacian $∆$$_{x,y}$
where $x$ and $y$ are both in $R^n$?

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate where you encountered this notation, how it is used, etc. This applies to your other questions as well: If you don't provide [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960), your questions are liable to be closed.

Answer (score -1):

The Laplacian operator is defined as :

$$\Delta = \nabla^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$$

$$\Delta_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})$$
$$\implies \Delta_x = \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} + \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x \partial y^2}$$

Similarly,

$$\implies \Delta_{x,y} = \frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^3 \partial y} + \frac{\partial^4}{\partial x \partial y^3}$$

Comment: hi rotayva ,what is the difference between $ \Delta$_{x,y}$  and $ \Delta$_ x$

Comment: $\Delta$ on its own is the Laplacian operator itself, whereas, $\Delta_{x,y}$ could be meant to denote the successive partial derivatives with respect to $x,y$ of the Laplacian operator.

Comment: @user317150 : check my edited answer.

Comment: thanks. If we want to write this formula In Cartesian coordinates in $ℝ^{2n}$ what be obtain?

Comment: @downvoters, comment please.

Comment: Note that $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$. I've certainly never seen the concept nor the notation of a partial derivative with respect to a multi-dimensional variable, and by your first equation it looks like you're thinking about the Laplacian on functions $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ rather than, say, $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. In PDEs, $\Delta_x$ is a common notation for the Laplacian with respect to the $n$-dimensional argument denoted as $x$, i.e. $\Delta_x f(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_{x_i}^2 f(x,y)$.